# Driving multiple outputs using a function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

VB won't execute the code when Cells(x,y) is called inside a function.

Hi Guys,
I am new to VBA and I am looking for some help. I am writing a function to drive an output. However, I also want to assign values to different rows based on a certain set of conditions. I was using Cells(i,2).value inside a function to assign values to different rows. But, VBA won't execute Cells(i,2) inside a function. It just terminates and gives "#VALUE!" as output.

Any help to resolve this issue will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

```
Function FindKP(Time, Curr_SP, IAC, Current, KInt, Output)
Dim K As Integer
For K = 1 To 200 Step 1
  For i = 7 To 40005
     If (Time(i) <> Time(i - 1)) Then
       cells(i, 2) = (Curr_SP / IAC - Current(i - 1) / IAC) * K * 0.0005
     Else
       cells(i, 2) = Output(i - 1)
     End If
  Next i
  P = 0
  For i = 7 To 40005
    If (Output(i) > Output(i - 1)) And Output(i) > (Curr_SP / IAC) Then
      Curr_Max = Output(i)
      P = 1
    End If
    If (P = 1) And (Output(i) < Output(i - 1)) Then
      Curr_Min = Output(i)
    End If
  Next
  If (Curr_Max < 1.1 * Curr_SP And Curr_Min > 0.9 * Curr_SP) Then
    FindKP = K
  End If
Next
End Function
```

Comment: A function called from a worksheet cannot change the values of other cells than the one that called it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Convert your Function to a normal `Sub` procedure.